# Carrierwave pdf local upload duplicates on :fog. Not doing it on :file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a very strange bug i been fighting with for a day now.

I'm trying to make an automatic uploader for uploading hundreds of PDF-files and putting them into categories from my local computer to my remote Amazon s3 server using Carrierwave.

When i run it with :file in my pdf_uploader everything is working as it should be, but when i run it with fog trying to save them on the Amazon s3 server everything is duplicated. And not like 1,1,2,2,3,3 but 1,2,3,1,2,3

*(i already have two image_uploaders and i tried uploading from a local directory earlier on with images, so the server and connection should be set up right)*

Here are my files:

```
#routes.rb 
get "upload_pdfs/now" => "pdf_categories#upload_pdfs", as: "upload_pdfs"
```

---

```
#pdf_categories_controller.rb
def upload_pdfs

    path = "/Users/bruger/Desktop/DENHER"

    Dir.foreach(path) do |category_path|

        next if folder_or_file_excluded? category_path
        pdf_category = PdfCategory.create!(title: category_path)

        Dir.foreach("#{path}/#{category_path}") do |file_path|  

            next if folder_or_file_excluded? file_path

            pdf_file_without_file_ending = remove_last_obj_in_arr file_path.split(".")


                new_pdf = Pdf.new(
                            title: pdf_file_without_ending,
                            pdf_category_id: pdf_category.id,
                            )

                #### SOMETHING IS HAPPENING HERE! ###
                File.open(path + "/" + category_path + "/" + file_path) do |file_from_path|
                    new_pdf.file = file_from_path
                    new_pdf.save!
                end
                #### SOMETHING IS HAPPENING HERE! ###

        end # file_path

    end # category_path
    redirect_to root_path
end

def is_integer? thing
    thing.to_i.to_s == thing
end 

def remove_last_obj_in_arr array
    new_array = array.first array.size - 1
    new_array.join(".")
end

def folder_or_file_excluded? folder_file
    list = %w(Fravalgt Fravalg Valgt fra fravalg fravalgt JPEG . .git DS_Store .. .DS_Store image_upload.rb)
    list.include? folder_file   
end
```

---

```
#pdf_uploader.rb
class PdfUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

      storage :fog

      def store_dir
        "pdf/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end

      def extension_whitelist
        %w(pdf PDF)
      end

    end
```

Have you experienced anything like this or do you have a clue?

Please. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There's a lot of (irrelevant) stuff going on in your code, which makes it hard to see what the actual problem is ... Can you try to produce a *minimal* example that demonstrates the issue? See: [mcve]

Comment: Looks like you're double looping. try this: https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/4d7b6ac8a5c3d6eef45b77cdd5c4556f